# Scrollable list with fixed button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some button with dropdown list.

`Example:`   [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16589/)

As you can see list is scrollable, but I want to add button to the bottom and it should be fixed. How could I accomplish that?

Comment: fiddle is not working

Comment: Please copy-paste your code to the question like the popup said when you tried to post only the jsfiddle link. Don't go around the block by code-highlighting something that isn't code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the button after the `ul` like, and let the scroll only on the `ul`:

```
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
     <ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option6" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 6</a></li>
</ul>
<button>btn</button>
     </div>
```

If you set in the CSS a smaller ul you can see it:

```
    ul{
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height: 100px; 
}
```

here:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2ukymj1/)

Comment: Yeah it's almost what I want except that it messes up li style when dropdown-menu class added to div.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add an option but should be a button?
put it on the list or not

```
var options = [];

$( '.dropdown-menu a' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {

   var $target = $( event.currentTarget ),
       val = $target.attr( 'data-value' ),
       $inp = $target.find( 'input' ),
       idx;

   if ( ( idx = options.indexOf( val ) ) > -1 ) {
      options.splice( idx, 1 );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', false ) }, 0);
   } else {
      options.push( val );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', true ) }, 0);
   }

   $( event.target ).blur();

   console.log( options );
   return false;
});

ul{
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height: 150px; 
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select 
          <i class="caret"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option6" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="some-option7" tabIndex="-1"><input type=button value="something"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="small" data-value="some-option7" tabIndex="-1"><input type=button value="something-else"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```